# Excel: Dynamic change cell with Date/Time when any other cell is changed in the worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to decypher a formula which will stamp auto Date/Time or some text when I change any random cell (more instances) inside some certain range (for instance A1:K45).

What I did is for one cell:

```
=IF(H6<>"CS";"Revision "&TEXT(TODAY();"TTMMJJJJ")& " MVV"&"Confidential Information!";K1)
```

But what about if I change something in another cell (other than H6, more cells at the time), is there a way to reference it without VBA?

Comment: not without VBA. =today() will update whenever the workbook is calculated.

Comment: As @PeterH noted, that formula listed above will update the time every time the workbook is opened or calculated.  I did this once with VBA but never figured out how to do this with only formulas.

Comment: @PeterH Yea...thats what I was afraid of... but I cant use Macros in my specific file. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @wbeard52  Yes I know...thats a reason I asked if there is any possibility to avoid Macros... but anyways thanks for comment =)